# sql server get the latest date from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the results listed below, but I get all records. Can you help?
wohead table:

```
part_code       run_date    wo_numb    run_number   cost_ctr    wo.status
7DADP0178PL03   3/23/2021   2010086202  969582       20            E
7DADP0178PL03   2/2/2021    3010084505  958761       30            C
7DADP0178PL03   12/29/2020  2010083235  951003       20            C
7DADP0312PL03   4/20/2021   3010087320  975966       30            C
7DADP0312PL03   3/31/2021   2010086579  971672       20            E
7DADP0312PL03   3/9/2021    3010085763  966756       30            C
7DADP0312PL03   2/16/2021   2010085046  961714       20            C
7DADP0312PL03   1/26/2019   2010084194  956522       20            C
```

Works but brings back all dates.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT wh1.part_code, wh1.run_date, wh1.wo_numb, wh1.run_number
    FROM wohead wh1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT whi.part_code,
      Max(whi.run_date) AS maxdate,
      whi.wo_numb,
      whi.run_number
    FROM wohead whi
    GROUP BY whi.part_code,
      whi.wo_numb,
      whi.run_number,
      whi.run_date) wh2 ON wh1.wo_numb = wh2.wo_numb AND
        wh1.run_number = wh2.run_number AND
        wh1.run_date = wh2.maxdate AND
        wh1.part_code = wh1.part_code
    WHERE wh1.cost_ctr = '20' AND
    wh1.wo_status = 'C' AND
    wh1.part_code IN ( '7DADP0312PL03', '7DADP0178PL03') AND
    wh1.run_date > 1 / 1 / 20
    GROUP BY wh1.part_code, wh1.run_date, wh1.wo_numb, wh1.run_number
    ORDER BY wh1.part_code, wh1.run_date DESC
```

Desired results:

```
part_code       run_date    wo_numb     run_number  cost_ctr    wo.status
7DADP0178PL03   12/29/2020  2010083235  951003      20          C
7DADP0312PL03   2/16/2021   2010085046  961714      20          C
```

Comment: can you edit your question to format the table, and query?...

Comment: Why is there no primary key in this table ? Or am  I missing something ?

Comment: I want to get the latest run_date per part_code and only include cost_ctr = 20 AND status = C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest `run_date` per `part_code` and only include `cost_ctr = 20 AND status = C`

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES wh1.part_code, wh1.run_date, wh1.wo_numb, wh1.run_number
FROM wohead wh1
WHERE wh1.cost_ctr = 20 AND wh1.status = 'C'
ORDER BY row_number() over(partition by wh1.part_code  order by wh1.run_date desc)
```